# Calling imported javascript from Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, bulma

I'm trying to use the `bulma-calendar` extension in my Angular 6 project and so in `angular.json` I add the `bulma-calendar.min.js` file to the scripts section.

What I can't figure out now is how to actually call that code.  I know it makes an export of `bulmaCalendar` but I'm not familiar enough with Angular to know how to reference that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you import it:

`import * as BulmaCalendar from '.your-path'`

Because Bulma calendar exports a constructor function:

```
export default class bulmaCalendar extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(selector, options = {}) {
```

You can instainiate it like:

```
let bulmaInstance = new BulmaCalendar('.some-selector', { option1: someval } )
```